# Rotate Array in Go

Tags: go, slice

This is a LeetCode problem: [189. Rotate Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/description/):

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is
>   non-negative.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k = 3
>   Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

And here is my solution:

```
func rotate(nums []int, k int)  {
    k = k % len(nums)
    nums = append(nums[k:],nums[0:k]...)
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

It is a straight forward algorithm but it does not work.

I am new to Go. I suppose `nums` is passed by value and changes to `nums` won't affect the real `nums`.

How can I get this right?

Comment: You must return nums. Read about how slices work in Go in the Blog.

Comment: slice already point to an array so there is no need to point to them separately. As @Volker suggested you should return your slice after modifying the same

Answer (score 8):

In Go, all arguments are passed by value.

A Go slice is represented at runtime by a slice descriptor:

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

If you change any of the slice descriptor values in a function then communicate the change, typically by returning the changed slice descriptor.

---

Your `rotate` function changes the values of the slice `num` pointer to the underlying array and the slice capacity, so return `num`.

For example, after I fixed the bugs in your `rotate` algorithm,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func rotate(nums []int, k int) []int {
    if k < 0 || len(nums) == 0 {
        return nums
    }

    fmt.Printf("nums %p array %p len %d cap %d slice %v\n", &nums, &nums[0], len(nums), cap(nums), nums)

    r := len(nums) - k%len(nums)
    nums = append(nums[r:], nums[:r]...)

    fmt.Printf("nums %p array %p len %d cap %d slice %v\n", &nums, &nums[0], len(nums), cap(nums), nums)

    return nums
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

    fmt.Printf("nums %p array %p len %d cap %d slice %v\n", &nums, &nums[0], len(nums), cap(nums), nums)

    nums = rotate(nums, 3)

    fmt.Printf("nums %p array %p len %d cap %d slice %v\n", &nums, &nums[0], len(nums), cap(nums), nums)
}
```

Output:

```
nums 0xc00000a080 array 0xc00001a1c0 len 7 cap 7 slice [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
nums 0xc00000a0c0 array 0xc00001a1c0 len 7 cap 7 slice [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
nums 0xc00000a0c0 array 0xc00001a240 len 7 cap 8 slice [5 6 7 1 2 3 4]
nums 0xc00000a080 array 0xc00001a240 len 7 cap 8 slice [5 6 7 1 2 3 4]
```

Reference: [The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Answer (score 2):

Answering this late as i came across this while reading the book "The Go Programming language". It presents a quite elegant algo to use the reverse function and apply it thrice to achieve the desired rotation by k elems. Something like this

```
// function to rotate array by k elems (3 reverse method)
func rotate(arr []int, k int) {
    reverse(arr[:k])
    reverse(arr[k:])
    reverse(arr)
}
```

Please note, you will have to write a reverse function. Go does not provide one. This is an O(n) solution and takes O(1) space.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to the same hackerrank [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem)

```
func rotateLeft(d int32, arr []int32) []int32 {
    for ; d > 0 ; d-- {
        left := arr[0]
        arr = arr[1:]
        arr = append(arr, left)        
    }
    return arr
}
```

Comment: I just learned a thing, didn't know you could do for loop with semi colon like that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way do rotate a float 32 slice, you can change it for another type.

```
//RotateF32Slice positive n rotate to the left, negative to right
func RotateF32Slice(slice []float32, n int) (rotateSlice []float32) {
    var begin []float32
    var end []float32
    size := len(slice)
    rotateSlice = make([]float32, size)

    nAbs := math.Abs(float64(n))

    if int(nAbs) > size {
        remainder, _ := QuotientAndRemainderF32(float32(n), float32(size))
        n = int(remainder)
    }

    if n != 0 {
        if n > 0 {
            index := size - n
            begin = slice[index:]
            end = slice[0:index]
            copy(rotateSlice, begin)
            copy(rotateSlice[n:], end)
        } else {
            n = int(nAbs)
            index := size - n
            begin = slice[n:]
            end = slice[0:n]
            copy(rotateSlice, begin)
            copy(rotateSlice[index:], end)
        }
    } else {
        copy(rotateSlice, slice)
    }

    return rotateSlice
}

//QuotientAndRemainderF32 Computes the integer quotient and the remainder of the inputs. This function rounds floor(x/y) to the nearest integer towards -inf.
func QuotientAndRemainderF32(x, y float32) (Remainder, Quotient float32) {
    Quotient = float32(math.Floor(float64(x / y)))
    Remainder = x - y*Quotient
    return Remainder, Quotient
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions

Solution 1 :

```
func rotate(ar []int,d,n int) []int{
    var newArray []int
    for i:=0;i<d;i++{
        newArray = ar[1:n]
        newArray = append(newArray,ar[0])
        ar = newArray
    }

    return ar
}
```

Solution 2 :

```
func rotateR(ar []int,d,n int) []int{
    ar = append(ar[d:n],ar[0:d]...)
    return  ar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func rotate(nums []int, k int) {
    k = k % len(nums)
    result := append(nums[len(nums)-k:], nums[:len(nums)-k]...)
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        nums[i] = result[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked for many of array rotating but not for hundreds nums[].

```
func rotate(nums []int, k int)  {
    for count:=k; count>0; count--{
        if len(nums) >= 1 && len(nums) <= 10^5 {
            for i:=len(nums)-1; i>0; i--{
                nums[i], nums[i-1] = nums[i-1], nums[i]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is
> non-negative.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k = 3 Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
> Blockquote

First, for k=3, shouldn't be the output [4,5,6,7,1,2,3] ?

For most array operations, it is always simplier to add elements to a newly created array rather than change the source array. If the array is not really large (takes Gigs of memory / billions of items, etc..), you can use a function that adds elements to the newly created array in the order you require and returns new one:

```golang
// GO 1.18
func rot[T any](slice []T, k int) (newSlice []T){
    l := len(slice)
    for i := range slice {
        newSlice = append(newSlice, slice[(k+i) % l])
    }
    return
}

fmt.Printf("Slice %v after rotation %v\n", []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, rot[int]([]int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 3))
//Slice [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] after rotation [4 5 6 7 1 2 3]
```

If you insist on using "slicing", the code looks like this:

```golang
func rotationBySlicing[T any](slice []T, k  int) (newSlice []T) {
    if len(slice) == 0 {
        return slice
    }
    return append(slice[(k%len(slice)):],slice[0:k%len(slice)]...)
}


fmt.Printf("Array %v after rotation %v\n", []string{}, rotationBySlicing[string]([]string{},1))
    fmt.Printf("Array %v after rotation %v\n", []string{"a"}, rotationBySlicing[string]([]string{"a"},1))
    fmt.Printf("Array %v after rotation %v\n", []string{"a","b"}, rotationBySlicing[string]([]string{"a","b"},1))
    fmt.Printf("Array %v after rotation %v\n", []string{"a","b","c"}, rotationBySlicing[string]([]string{"a","b","c"},1))
    fmt.Printf("Array %v after rotation %v\n", []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, rotationBySlicing[string]([]string{"a", "b", "c", "d"},1))
    fmt.Printf("Slice %v after rotation %v\n", []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, rotationBySlicing[int]([]int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 3))


Array [] after rotation []
Array [a] after rotation [a]
Array [a b] after rotation [b a]
Array [a b c] after rotation [b c a]
Array [a b c d] after rotation [b c d a]
Array [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] after rotation [4 5 6 7 1 2 3]
```

Also instruction says:

> where k is non-negative

, for completeness the code should handle case when k is less than 0

Comment: This code is rather inefficient... better use the solution provided by @peterSO
func Rot[T any](slice []T, k int) []T {
 r := len(slice) - k%len(slice)
 return append(slice[r:], slice[:r]...)
}

Comment: @truetoastedcode before you start minus me for code inefficiency, at least make a benchmark. Then come and argue about how inefficient the code is. With two answers, you aren't the right one to come here and minus the others.

Comment: I do understand your anger... however I measured the runtime of a program where I've rotated slices alot and it was ~6x faster with this solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I preferred this algorithm below because I wanted to keep slice capacity the same:

```golang
// Rotation by keeping the capacity same
func Rotate(nums []int, k int) {
    k %= len(nums)
    new_array := make([]int, len(nums))
    copy(new_array[:k], nums[len(nums)-k:])
    copy(new_array[k:], nums[:len(nums)-k])
    copy(nums, new_array)
}
```

Also, I tested it in Leet code and it looks good :)

[image: fast rotation algorithm in golang]

You can also add a condition at the top of your function to make it ready for negative shifts (rotates),

Whole code again:

```golang
func Rotate(nums []int, k int) {
    k %= len(nums)
    // Condition below is added.
    if k < 0 {
        k += len(nums)
    }
    new_array := make([]int, len(nums))
    copy(new_array[:k], nums[len(nums)-k:])
    copy(new_array[k:], nums[:len(nums)-k])
    copy(nums, new_array)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work because `[]byte` is a slice which is sort of a "pointer to an array". Doing:

```
func f(v []T) {
  v = ... //
}
```

won't have any observable effect for the caller. Assuming your `append` way is correct (didn't really check it) you could do something like this:

```
func rotate(nums []int, k int) {
    k = k % len(nums)
    temp := append(nums[k:], nums[0:k]...)
    copy(nums, temp) // this actually writes to where nums points to
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    rotate(nums ,3)
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```