# How to translate or shift values in slice in golang?

Tags: go, slice

I have a slice in golang, say [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10], and I would like to efficiently shift the values to different indexes such as a shift of 5 would yield [6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5].

I have come up with a solution below, but wondering if there is a built-in or better way to accomplish this?

https://play.golang.org/p/tkYPkGmffQ1

Comment: If you're looking for a better solution than your own, your solution should be part of your question, not an answer.

Comment: YO @Adrian ! Done done done done

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833673/rotate-array-in-go

Also see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Answer (score 3):

```
func translation(nums []int, n int) []int {
    n = n % len(nums)
    return append(nums[n:len(nums):len(nums)], nums[:n]...)
}
```

is sufficient.

`nums[n:len(nums):len(nums)]` is a "[full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)" which ensures that the resulting slice has no excess capacity (even if `nums` does). Since it has 0 extra capacity, `append` will have to allocate a new array to place the extra items, and the returned slice won't be an alias of the original slice — unless `n` is 0. If you need to handle the case of `0`, then you can do it with a `copy`.

Comment: doesn't this incur an extra alloc - versus pre-alloc'ing the slice size?  https://play.golang.org/p/IPOCAP8EZTH

Comment: @colminator mine does one alloc in `append`, yours does one alloc in `make`. The slicing operations don't alloc.

Comment: (`append` might alloc slightly more space than needed, but that's a different matter, and not one that I would worry about in *most* situations).

Comment: ok that clarifies things. When I saw a slice entering a function that is smaller than its eventual target value - I had assumed that incur a slight inefficiency. And yes - as playground example shows - for a slice of size 5 - the returned slice capacity is 8.